# How do I get Kongs X-Forwarded-Prefix Header into Spring Boot Application and its HATEOAS links?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, header, spring-hateoas, kong

i'm having a Spring Boot application that is accessed through Kong API Gateway. Because of this, the self links provided by Spring are wrong.

The URL to access my application via Kong is the following:
    https://api.anything.de/myapplication/test/countries/

But the self links look like that:
    https://api.anything.de/countries/5a4cf88a45a64a97a7cdb38c

So as you can see, the prefix "/myapplication/test" is missing in the self links.

Thats why i tried to add X-Forwarded-Prefix in the config of Kong.

This is my entry in the config.yml of Kong:

```
  - name: MyApplicationTest
    plugins:
      - name: request-transformer
        attributes:
          enabled: true
          config:
            add:
              headers:
                - 'X-Forwarded-Prefix:/myapplication/test'
    attributes:
      uris:
        - /myapplication/test
      strip_uri: true
      preserve_host: false
      upstream_url: 'http://<IP>/my-application-test'
```

In the application.yml of my application I have this:

```
server:
    port: 8080
    compression:
        enabled: true
        mime-types: application/json
    use-forward-headers: true
```

My class Application.java looks like that:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    FilterRegistrationBean forwardedHeaderFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(new ForwardedHeaderFilter());
        filterRegistrationBean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }
}
```

Because I wanted to know if my applictaion receives the Header from Kong I have a end point to see the headers. But there is no X-Forwarded-Prefix header.

Does anybody know what I'm missing or have an idea how to fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring 5.1, then indeed, Forwarding has been significantly altered for security reasons.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/pull/717 is currently under review so that Spring HATEOAS can integrate properly with this breaking change in Spring MVC.